# How to ensure if an email was sent after a network outage?

Tags: networking, email, outlook-web-access

I was writing the body of the message, using **Outlook web app**, while the Internet connection crashed for 10-15 seconds.

After the connection got stable (I was in the same page, without refreshing), I clicked Send message and it was sent without any problem being shown (**it was also appeared at Outbox**).

But **how do I ensure that the email was actually sent?** Besides asking the recipient.

Because usually when you, for example, fill in a form, connection crashes for a bit, then you hit submit, it shows errors. That would mean that Outlook Web can retain the connectivity even for a short connection outage (after the connection returns I mean)?

*PS: I know this may be a stupid question, but I just want to ensure things (even the simple ones) I don't know 100%.*

Comment: Check your Sent folder? If it wasn't sent it would still be in Outbox

Comment: That works too, thanks. But I shall wait for any other explanation aswell, if that's not the only one.

Comment: If you want more reassurance, right click the message and select Open Delivery Report. There you can see submission time, delivery time, etc

Comment: If you are using OWA that means MS Exchange which means all sent mail will appear in the Sent folder unless you move it

Comment: "That would mean that Outlook Web" - This didn't happen,  OWA is a feature of Exchange and/or Office 365 in either case if the connection to the server is lost the page will not function.

Answer (score 0):

You can ensure that a message was delivered by checking the Delivery Report.

From the Outlook Web App: Right-click the message in question and click `Open Delivery Report` from the pop-up menu.

From Outlook desktop: Open the message, go to the `File` tab, click `Info` and then `Open Delivery Report`. This will open a browser window with the report loaded in the Outlook Web App.

Comment: I guess that would work, if I actually had Read Receipt enabled, because it doesn't show me the Delivery Report option at the pop-menu...

Comment: You don't need Read Receipt enabled for this. Right-clicking the message in the Sent folder doesn't show the Open Delivery Report option?

Comment: Here's an alternate way to check the delivery reports. Does that show anything? https://kb.intermedia.net/article/2576

Comment: I tried that link, but I can't login at their service.
Also, I read that like more than year now, Microsoft removed Delivery Report from the options menu :S.

Comment: You don't need to log into their service, ignore that step. Just login to your OWA and follow the steps from step 2 edit: oh, didn't notice that. What version of OWA are you using?

Comment: I'm on Exchange 2010, but for newer versions it seems you are right: https://www.reddit.com/r/Office365/comments/5in9iu/where_did_message_delivery_reports_go_in_owa/?st=j5d81ueo&sh=d733530e You can still access them from within Outlook, according to that thread

Comment: Sorry for not responding. After your last comment I was searching for the OWA version it is used and eventually I found out that without ticking the Reports being sent, there wouldn't be any report for any email. By default now is off, so I can't have any report.